# django rest issue: get_extra_actions with listApiView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project using the [Django REST API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org) framework. When I run the project locally I get the following error:

```
File "/home/asad/PycharmProjects/microshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 153, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: type object 'CustomerListAPIViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

I searched on Google and StackOverflow, but could not found any solution.

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'phone_number', 'address', ]
```

**views.py**

```
class CustomerListAPIViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from accounts_app.views import CustomerListAPIViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'customer/', CustomerListAPIViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with your view's naming. This create a confusion.

You are actually creating an `APIView` subclass. But you are naming it as `ViewSet`. You can register `ViewSet` classes with rest_framework routers not `APIView`s.

You can do following changes to make your view runnable.

Views File:

```py
class CustomerListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

URLS File:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from accounts_app.views import CustomerListAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^customer/', CustomerListAPIView.as_view(), name='customer-list')
]
```

The other way around is defining an actual ViewSet class, but the structure will be different.

Comment: so basically generics.ListAPIView cant bind with rest router?

Comment: Documentation does not implicitly says that but it seems that way. Please have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/